# Показ,подсчёт кликов и почасовая статистика

Tags: php, javascript

Вывожу картинки, берутся из бд, таблица **images** на сайте. После нужно посчитать, сколько их посмотрело, а сколько кликнуло.
Поля таблицы **images** к примеру `id, watches, clicks`

После этого ещё вывести статистику по этим картинкам, кого больше кликали. Статистику можно посмотреть как в определённый промежуток дат, так и за один час.

Помогите справиться с такой задачей.

Я пока только додумался при каждом дёрганьи картинки из базы добавить +1 в поле `watches`, а при клике `ajaxom` передавать `id` на `php` и делать +1 в `watches`. Не слишком ли прямолинейно и глупо?

Но теперь стоит задача, как подсчитывать статистику? Ведь для этого нужно будет эту статистику записывать в бд. Сделать отдельную таблицу вида `id=картинки watches=1 date=дата показа`?

Мне кажется мои мысли слегка бредовы, кто сталкивался с таким, подскажите, как вы с этим справлялись.

Comment: если вы хотите хранить время каждого просмотра и клика, то логично было бы их положить в отдельные таблицы - `clicks(img_id reference images,datetime) watches(img_id reference images,datetime), images(id,src)`

Comment: Ничего бредового, все норм, @Darth Вам все расписал

Comment: @Darth это-то понятно.Но не будет ли таблица watches слишком огромной? При каждом обновлении страницы и выводе 10 картинок в неё будет добавляться 10 записей и чистить её будет нельзя,т.к. статистика пропадёт. 
Боюсь представить сколько там накопится записей например за месяц или за полгода

Comment: @IgorSergeevich к вам такой же вопрос. Ничего страшного если записей в таблице watches будет около 10 миллионов?

Comment: @ThreegunD если вы хотите статистику, то вам в любом случае понадобиться где то хранить 10 миллионов (или сколько у вас будет просмотров) временных меток

Comment: Ничего страшного, но Вам необходимо будет оптимизировать базу в зависимости от выбранной СУБД, т.е. добавить индексы и т.д. Кста, какую субд используете? Посмотреть в сторону кеширования, в общем много зависит от ОС и железа

Comment: Как вариант, определите минимальные требовани, статистика по минутам - записывайте в минуту (10 раз открыли в минуту, записали 10 в одну строку а не создали 10 строк). Возмите другую бд для статистики (ClickHouse, HP Vertica ...), если это имеет смысл конечно, в большинстве случаем вам вашей логики хватит на долго